# Inject ILoggingFactory into Service library

Tags: serilog, loggerfactory

I have a console application that I am using Serilog in.  I am trying to inject logging into my services library but I never see the log messages.  It seems when I step through the code that even though I am creating a Singleton LoggerFactory, the library is creating a new instance of the factory.

Console Application

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
loggerFactory.AddSerilog(GetLoggerConfiguration());
_loggerIdentity = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<WorkerBroker>();

IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.TryAddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
_provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

// Inject my service
var service = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyService>(_provider);
```

Constructor for Service where injection is occurring (in library)

```
public MyService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<WebCreditService>();
}
```

Later in the Service I will try to log something and nothing shows in the log but I do see messages from the Console application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a little more research and I actually just needed to add the logger factory I created to the ServicesCollection.

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
loggerFactory.AddSerilog(GetLoggerConfiguration());
_loggerIdentity = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<WorkerBroker>();

IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton(loggerFactory);
_provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

// Add console logging
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(new LoggerFactory()
                .AddConsole(configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                .AddSerilog()
                .AddDebug());
            serviceCollection.AddLogging();

```
        // Add Serilog logging           
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(configuration["Serilog:LogFile"])
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
```

But you have to consider configuration in appsettings file also.

Seen here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1218350/Elasticsearch-Kibana-and-Docker-using-NET-Standard